# Обрезать лишнии куски изображения

Tags: c#

В ходе работы приложения создаю пустое изображение

```
Image bg = Image.FromFile(path)
var img = new Bitmap(bg.Width, bg.Height);
```

Ширина и высота которого равна фоновому изображению, и используется только для обозначения границ.
После генерирую несколько объектов на этом пустом изображении (границы объектов заранее не исвестны), и по окончанию, мне нужно обрезать пустое пространство снизу и справа, т.к. там остались ненужные пустые куски, из-за которых я не могу корректно наложить сгенерированное изображение на фоновое, так, что бы сгенерированное было по центру

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bg)) {
    g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
    g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(
        (bg.Width - img.Width) / 2, 
        (bg.Height - img.Height) / 2,
        se_img.Width,
        se_img.Height));
}
```

Вопрос: как обрезать всё пустое пространство?

Я могу циклом получить все пиксели и узнать координаты всех крайних пикселей, и по ним обрезать, или я могу в ходе генерации определять крайние элементы, и по ним обрезать, но можно ли сделать процесс обрезания проще?

P.S. использую `System.Drawing`

Comment: Если все объекты у вас есть где то в памяти и у объектов есть позиция + высота/ширина, то в чем проблема по ним найти границы?

Comment: @tym32167 такой вариант был описан в вопросе. И вопрос заключался в том, как убрать края, не заморачиваясь с сохранением позиции крайних объектов, которые, в моём случае, проблематично достать из-за специфики построения

Comment: мне кажется, вам надо добавить больше контекста в вопрос. С одной стороны ваш вопрос уже созержит ответ. С другой стороны - вы просите сказать, какой от вариантов лучше, при этом не предоставляя всю картину. Основываясь на том, что вы показали пока что - оба ваших варианта рабочие, но я бы не пытался пойти путем сравнения пикселей, так как это меодленней +  какие то из фигур могут быть цвета вашей пустоты и вы их можете обрезать.

Comment: @tym32167 суть вопроса состоит в том, есть ли готовое решение в виде метода а-ля `img.CropToContent()` в котором реализован эффективный способ нахождения краёв контена. Если такого нет - буду использовать один из описанных варинатов

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но мне кажется, что готового ничего такого нет.

Comment: [Find the rectangle area of image to Crop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24593864/312041)

Comment: @tym32167 получается, единственное решение подобной задачи - перебирать каждый пиксель. Хорошо, время заморачиваться с нахождением крайних объектов при построении.

Comment: Ну это не так сложно, как кажется. Я когда то решал [похожую задачу](https://tym32167.blogspot.com/2013/09/linqpad.html).